# Leave tracks on solder layer - Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I want to create a PCB with some traces on the solder layer, so I can reinforce them with tin.

Those traces will use AC current and about 5 amps. So I want to create some traces with 3mm wide and tin above.

I just see options to create traces on top layer and bottom layer. How can I create a rule to create those traces on solder layer? I am not sure which layer I need to choose neither.

Comment: Conductivity of copper is 6x of solder. In other words, it is almost not worth the trouble.

Comment: How can I calculate the width of a copper trace for 5 amps in 220v AC? I am afraid of creating traces too small.

Comment: http://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html

Comment: If you have the option available, you should use thick copper for this trace. For example, 2 oz copper (which is around 70 um). This is something that you specify in a "fab drawing" which you send to the board manufacturer.

Comment: 2oz copper is 0.07mm thick, so adding 1mm of solder, even if it's 6x less conductive, still means reducing the resistance by more than 50%, plus it adds a significant amount of thermal mass and (slightly) more surface area. If you are putting a lot of current through the trace this makes a big difference.

Comment: Is it feasible to add 1mm of solder? I guess, for a wide trace, it might be.

Comment: I think my pcb supplier just use 35 um for traces (Elecrow). But I will ask about using 70 um for some tracks. Since it is a small batch, I don't have problems in adding some solder in those tracks (they are short and 6-7 for each pcb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove solder mask above the trace, just select all the segments of the trace and use PCB inspector to set the `Solder Mask Expantion Mode` to `From Rule`.

[image]

If you're not fussy about how the paste is added, you can also define paste expansion in the same place.

Comment: Hey what's the purpose of adding extra tin??